# How to change default template options of a Geb Page?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, geb

I am using Geb 0.9.0. I recently found out about Geb's [template options](http://www.gebish.org/manual/snapshot/pages.html#template_options). I think that they can be very useful. But I want to use them after changing a few defaults across all my Pages. I want the `wait` parameter to default to `true`.

I tried reading the whole documentation for the options but couldn't find anything about how to change the defaults.

Comment: In case someone interested I raised the ticket at https://github.com/geb/issues/issues/373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not currently possible to change the defaults of template options. Please feel free to submit an issue in [the tracker](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB) if you would like to see it implemented in the future.

Nevertheless even if it was possible, I would suggest not using `true` as the default value for the `wait` option because it would make any failure caused by a missing element to be delayed by the amount of time defined in the default waiting preset. Also, resolving definitions for which element is not present will result in a delay.